# WiFi: Possible to simultaneouslty broadcast a WLAN network and connect to one on the same device?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, unix

### Question

Is it possible to simultaneously broadcast a WLAN network and connect to one on the same device?

I'm trying to broadcast a WLAN network and simultaneously connect to a different network at once. The goal is to allow a user to connect to the Pi via WLAN in their browser, enter their WiFi network credentials in an app running on the Pi, and then connect to their local WiFi network on the Pi.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

### Context

- **Device**: Raspberry Pi Model 3A+
- **Wireless Chipset:** Cypress CYW43455
- **WAP Management**: `hostapd`, `dnsmasq`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I updated the question with some additional context.

Comment: It is possible, but you will be limited to using the same WiFi channel for both connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Tim_Stewart said, it comes down to chipset. Run `iw list` and look at the section "valid interface combinations".

What you want is something like `#{ managed } >= 1` while at the same time `total >= 2`. If it is possible, there might be additional limitations with respect to number of simultaneous channels and/or BSSIDs. For more information, see also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401464/deciphering-the-output-of-iw-list-valid-interface-combinations).